# Truth about high quality HDMI cables

Tags: home-theater

My home theater setup specifically warrants a 25 feet HDMI cable. I have a Sony Bravia 55" LED TV 3D + 240Hz refresh rate, alongside a XBox One, Comcast digital cable and Blu Ray player. I went to BestBuy and they were trying to sell me an 8 meters (26.2 feet) AudioQuest HDMI cable that costs $299 and an 8 meters AudioQuest optical audio cable for $99. Their justification was that the quality deteriorates as the length of the HDMI cable increases and the AudioQuest cables have silver that provides excellent conductivity of audio and video signals. But when I took a look online (Amazon), I saw a rather large selection of HDMI cables that were significantly cheaper (under $25) and pretty good reviews. Technical specs-wise, they did not seem all that different or inferior to the AudioQuest cables. So I am very confused. Is there any particular criteria that I should use to form my decision? I want the best bang for the buck and at the same time, I want cables that provide the necessary quality and are reasonably future-proof, although the latter expectation is not crucial.

Comment: You need [monster cables](http://m.monsterproducts.com/1001.html), just ask Jimmy Fallon.

Comment: CNET says they are all the same in their articles [Why all HDMI cables are the same](http://www.cnet.com/news/why-all-hdmi-cables-are-the-same/), [Why all HDMI cables are the same, part 2](http://www.cnet.com/news/why-all-hdmi-cables-are-the-same-part-2/), [Still more reasons why all HDMI cable are the same](http://www.cnet.com/news/still-more-reasons-why-all-hdmi-cable-are-the-same/), and [4K HDMI cables (are nonsense)](http://www.cnet.com/news/4k-hdmi-cables-are-nonsense/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. There's obviously so much written about this, it looks like I am not the first or last person wondering about this. Now I'm just wondering if i should purchase from a local store or an online store like Amazon.

Comment: You can get one for like $3 at Amazon. Thats what I did, and it works just fine. Let's face it, it's a cable. Hard to mess that up too badly.

Comment: Your problem is buying at bestbuy.  They make so little selling the tvs.  Cables with 600% markup is where they make their money.  I've always had good experiences with cables from monoprice - dirt cheap but work just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on Signal Processing Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

Save your money and buy the cheap cables. They're the same. The "premium cable" game is nothing more than a big scam.

Comment: Yup. $2.50 cables work great.

Comment: I'd be happy to find a $2.5 cable if it is 25' long, supports 3D and certified for in wall (UL3).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @iLikeDirt - it doesn't matter. The thing is, HDMI is digital; it's pretty much work or don't work. You can't just get a "degraded signal". If you're running full resolution and you don't see it breaking up or severely pixelating, you're good. Buy cheap cables and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I bought one of the $20 variety of 8 metre cables with mini HDMI connector on one end and a full HDMI on the other.

It runs 4000p just fine.  No artifacts, no noise, no distractions.  It noticeably lacks silver, gold, and platinum.

Comment: Where did you buy the cable? If you don't mind, can you share some information on your setup?

Comment: @WebUser: I bought it from Amazon, it was [this one](http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-Mini-Cable-15-feet/dp/B001M5BIX0) which it seems I have mismembered the length (only 5 metres) but the price puts me to shame as it now sells for less than $6.  I used it to connect a GoPro Hero 3 black edition to a production switcher like [this device](http://www.grassvalley.com/products/kayenne).

Answer (score -1):

[Finding the Right Cable](http://www.hdmi.org/consumer/finding_right_cable.aspx) -HDMI®

> The **High Speed HDMI cable** is designed and **tested to handle** video resolutions of 1080p and beyond, including advanced display technologies such as 4K, 3D, and Deep Color. If you are using any of these technologies, or if you are connecting your 1080p display to a 1080p content source, such as a Blu-ray Disc player, this is the recommended cable.

"HDMI is a horrible computer interface". -My IT guy

Comment: Propaganda, nothing more.

Comment: Category 1 cables will probably work, category 2 cables *will* work. Reputable suppliers also offer lifetime guarantees on their products.